# How to writte a file in c++, considering that everytime you run the code, the file keeps storing the previous data?

Tags: c++

I'm working in creating a file that contains the data that describes the position of a cell in fuction of time. I was adviced to use snprintf. These were the lines of code that I used to introduce the function:

int n_sample = 50;

char filename[101];

snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename),"dados_movimento_celula_%d.dat", n_sample);

The code runs, showing no errors, however, it keeps alterating the file by replacing the previous data with the new one, instead of just adding the new one set of data. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the file to hold the existing data and append new data to it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ofstream and open the file in append mode:

```
std::ofstream outFile;
outfile.open(fileName, std::ios_base::app);
outFile << content;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it really helped, however, if it wasn't too much to ask, I was wondering if there is some sort of way to keep adding the new data in a new collumn instead of just adding in the same column

Comment: @BárbaraPereira I'm afraid that is not possible. You may need to find a third party library or simply read the entire file each time and append a new column to the contents.